# Discord.py: how do i use cog for my discord bot to avoid commands in on_ready

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have made a discord bot that actually works, the problem is it's really slow and with searching in google i found out that making things in on_ready isnt actually good. I also converted from Client to bot. I wanted to also do things regularly in Cot like updating each members role once a day/month or year. But since i never actually used cot i can't really figure out how to use it. Im not sure if i have to make a Cot python file that i import into my main.py file and also how to start it. Also not sure how to do my things from on_ready in a Cot.
If anybody has some insight i would be greatfull!

I have posted my code below to show where i am currently

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ui import Button
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import time
import random
import string
import threading
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

#Getting objects that won't change to safe resources
guild = discord.Guild
emoji_doc = discord.Emoji
emoji_fold = discord.Emoji
emoji_back = discord.Emoji
access_channel = discord.TextChannel
password_channel = discord.TextChannel
deactivated_role = discord.Role
student_role = discord.Role
mod_role = discord.Role
admin_role = discord.Role

passwords = []


# Trying out Cog from the API Quickguide
#
#
utc = timezone.utc

# If no tzinfo is given then UTC is assumed.
time = time(hour=19, minute=45, tzinfo=utc)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.my_task.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.my_task.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(time=time)
    async def my_task(self):
        print("My task is running!")

#
#
# Cog end



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    #Get the non changing objects i use more often
    global guild
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, id=1182746047756390511)
    global emoji_doc
    emoji_doc = await guild.fetch_emoji(1209775651926839316)
    global emoji_fold
    emoji_fold= await guild.fetch_emoji(1209775678007017473)
    global emoji_back
    emoji_back= await guild.fetch_emoji(1209811147482464266)
    global access_channel
    access_channel = bot.get_channel(1184949536490262528)
    global password_channel
    password_channel = bot.get_channel(1209865792875659264)
    global deactivated_role
    deactivated_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="deactivated")
    global student_role
    student_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="student")
    global mod_role
    mod_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="mod")
    global admin_role
    admin_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="admin")
    
    #Post message in each channel of specific Category with a button file system
    for category in guild.categories:
        if "semester" in category.name.lower():
            for channel in category.channels:
                messages = [message async for message in channel.history(oldest_first=True)]
                if messages is not None:
                    for msg in messages:
                        if msg.author.name == bot.user.name:
                            print(msg)
                            await msg.delete()
                await sendTestFolder(channel, category.name.lower())
    
    #Check if for each year since 2021 there exists a password
    messages = [message async for message in password_channel.history(oldest_first=True)]
    year = 0
    password = ""
    needed_passwords = 0
    print(messages)
    global passwords
    if messages != []:
        print("Hat nachrichten")
        for msg in messages:
            try:
                date,password=msg.content.split('.')
                year = int(date)
                passwords.append(tuple((year,password)))
            except ValueError:
                msg.delete()
        if year < datetime.now().year:
            needed_passwords = datetime.now().year-year
    else:
        print("Hat Keine Nachrichten")
        year = 2021
        needed_passwords = datetime.now().year-year

    print(datetime.now().year)
    print(needed_passwords)
    if needed_passwords != 0 and needed_passwords < 10:
        for i in range(needed_passwords):
            pw = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for j in range(8))
            content_msg = str(year+1+i) + "." + pw
            passwords.append(tuple((year+1+i,pw)))

            await channel.send(content=content_msg)

    #Check each member if he has access to the discord
    for member in guild.members:
        if member != bot.user:
            await updateRoles(member)
    print("Finished initial role update")
    print("Cog läuft jetzt...")


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global guild
    global deactivated_role
    if member.guild.name == guild.name:
        await member.add_roles(deactivated_role)

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    global access_channel
    global deactivated_role
    if msg.channel == access_channel:
        if deactivated_role in msg.author.roles:
            await updateRoles(msg.author)


async def updateRoles(user):
    global access_channel
    global passwords
    global student_role
    global deactivated_role
    global mod_role
    global admin_role
    is_member = 0
    user_semester = 1
    print("Updating role of")
    print(user)
    print(access_channel)
    async for message in access_channel.history():
        if message == []:
            print("no passwords found")
        elif len(message.content) != 8 and message.content.isalpha() is not True:
            await message.delete()
        else:
            if message.author == user:
                print("Match in message")
                for pw in passwords:
                    print(pw[1])
                    print(message.content)
                    if pw[1] == message.content and is_member==0:
                        is_member = 1
                        current_roles = []
                        if student_role not in user.roles:
                            await user.send(content="Congratulations!!! You are now student in the XY discord-group!")
                        if admin_role in user.roles:
                            print("Has admin")
                            current_roles.append(admin_role)
                        if mod_role in user.roles:
                            print("Has mod")
                            current_roles.append(mod_role)
                        await user.edit(roles=current_roles)
                        await user.add_roles(student_role)
                        user_semester = ((datetime.now().year-pw[0])*2)
                        if datetime.now().month>7:
                            user_semester+=1
                        if user_semester<7:
                            semester_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name= str(user_semester)+". Semester")
                            await user.add_roles(semester_role)
                    elif pw[1] == message.content and is_member == 1:
                        await message.delete()
                if is_member == 0:
                    await message.delete()
    if is_member == 0:
        current_roles = []
        current_roles.append(deactivated_role)
        if admin_role in user.roles:
            print("Has admin")
            current_roles.remove(deactivated_role)
            current_roles.append(admin_role)
        if mod_role in user.roles:
            print("Has mod")
            current_roles.remove(deactivated_role)
            current_roles.append(mod_role)
        print("Deleting roles")
        await user.edit(roles=current_roles)




async def sendTestFolder(channel,category_name):
    path = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\Discord Bot Test\\"
    temp_path = path+category_name+"\\"+channel.name + "\\"
    if os.path.exists(temp_path):
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(temp_path)]
        view = discord.ui.View(timeout=None)
        num_button = 1
        row = 0
        for f in files:
            global emoji_doc
            emoji = emoji_doc
            if os.path.isdir(temp_path+"\\"+f):
                global emoji_fold
                emoji = emoji_fold
            if not num_button % 5:
                row += 1
            view.add_item(ButtonCreation(label=f,style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary,custom_id=f, emoji=emoji,row=row))
            num_button += 1
        await channel.send(temp_path.replace(path,''), view=view)


class ButtonCreation(Button):
    def __init__(self, label, style, emoji, custom_id, row):
        super().__init__(label=label, style=style, custom_id=custom_id, emoji=emoji, row=row)

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        path = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\Discord Bot Test\\"
        temp_path = ""
        go_back = 0
        message_content = interaction.message.content
        if self.label.lower() == "back":
            print("go back")
            self.view.clear_items()
            path_folders = interaction.message.content.split('\\')
            temp_path = path + "".join([str(path_folders[x] + "\\") for x in range(len(path_folders[:-2]))])
        else:
            temp_path = path + interaction.message.content
            if os.path.isfile(temp_path + self.label):
                print("give file")
                await interaction.user.send(file=discord.File(temp_path+self.label))
                go_back = 1
                self.view.clear_items()
            else:
                print("go folder")
                self.view.clear_items()
                temp_path += self.label + "\\"
                go_back = 1
        if os.path.exists(temp_path):
            files = [f for f in os.listdir(temp_path)]
            num_button = 1
            row = 0
            for f in files:
                global emoji_doc
                emoji = emoji_doc
                if os.path.isdir(temp_path + f):
                    global emoji_fold
                    emoji = emoji_fold
                if not num_button % 5:
                    row += 1
                self.view.add_item(ButtonCreation(label=f,style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary,custom_id=f, emoji=emoji,row=row))
                num_button += 1
            if go_back:
                if not num_button % 5:
                    row += 1
                global emoji_back
                emoji = emoji_back
                self.view.add_item(ButtonCreation(label="Back",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary,custom_id="Go Back", emoji=emoji,row=row))
            message_content = temp_path.replace(path,'')
            print(message_content)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=message_content, view=self.view)


bot.run('(°_°)')
```

The File system looks like this
[Filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Lf1.png)
[Filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8o5o.png)
And if you press on the file it sends it to you inside the dm

The passwords look like this
[Passoword channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmiHy.png)

The request_access channel only have the 8 letters of the password written by each member

I tried adding the cod with bot.add_cog just before starting the bot but i get an error that the await is outside a function.
also put it for testing into on_ready which seems to work but it doesnt actually do anything

Also no idea how to do the on_ready things only once on startup

EDIT:
I've got my first Cog running but im not quite sure how to use it,
could someone explain me if there is an advantage to have multiple cogs?
Like for example, one cog for on_ready, one cog for daily work, one cog for commands?
Does more cogs help making it faster or does it make it slower? Does it run parallel instead of sequentiell?
How to do buttons at on_ready that do something, or how to handle the callbacks?

And if someone would like an updated version of my code with cogs or also just my file system, let me know, i will then update the code once ive finished my project

Comment: Also if anyone has anything i can improve on my code design hmu, i come from c-programming and learned python on my own so any critic is nice to have

Comment: cog can make your code way more organized. And if you want to do any loading before running the bot. (E.g: loading from database). You could create a `main()` async function and do the work in there (Loading cog files, loading data from anywhere, start the bot). And if you want any task loop going, you could start them in `setup_hook()`

Comment: Thank you for answering me, i finally got the cogs to work and organized my bot a little bit more